# Why is "for" used in "for example/instance"?

Tags: phrases, prepositions

I have been looking at the interpretation of the word "for" in the phrases "for example" and "for instance", but I cannot make sense of it. The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for) lists 12 uses of "for" as a preposition, but to me, the "for" in the aforementioned phrases do not seem to match any of them.

Are these phrases some type of exceptions, where we can only interpret them jointly? In other words, is the "for" in these phrases not literally acting as a "for" preposition? Is this perhaps a phrase which came up as a simplification of what could be a literal yet longer alternative, like in

> I am a keen reader. **To give you an example of this**, last week alone I read fourteen books.

Comment: You may be overlooking definition 1: In support of, or in favour of (a person or policy).  Definition 7: Representing (the thing mentioned). 'For example' introduces a thing that represents a sample of the general category mentioned.

Comment: There is no meaning of _for_ in _for example_; it's a fixed phrase, descended from another fixed phrase (_for the sake of example_), which in turn is descended from a Latin fixed phrase (_exemplī grātiā_), which doesn't have a _for_. Instead grātiā, 'thanks, sake, grace' appears in the Ablative case (that's the long _ā_ at the end of _grātiā,_) and that has the same use as the _for_ in English, just like the possessive case of _exemplī_ has the same use as _of_ in _of example_. So there's no point in looking up prepositions in the dictionary. Mostly they don't mean anything.

Comment: You also tell tall storie**s**, fourteen book**s** in seven day**s** that's  two book**s** a day, every day for one week? Wow... :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Well, not all the material in constructed examples has to be taken from actual reality.  (Or, they might be short books.)

Comment: @aparente001 No, examples don't have to be veritable, but it helps if they are realistic and believable. I was also subtly pointing out that the term  
*book*  should be plural, which I see you picked up on or maybe not, but at least the example sentence is now grammatical.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yes.  I enjoy editing questions to make them look as nice as possible.  I probably overdo it....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

John Lawler:

> There is no meaning of *for* in *for example*; it's a fixed phrase, descended from another fixed phrase (*for the sake of example*), which in turn is descended from a Latin fixed phrase (*exemplī grātiā*), which doesn't have a *for*. Instead *grātiā*, 'thanks, sake, grace' appears in the Ablative case (that's the long *ā* at the end of *grātiā*), and that has the same use as the *for* in English, just like the possessive case of *exemplī* has the same use as *of* in *of example*. So there's no point in looking up prepositions in the dictionary. Mostly they don't mean anything.

Let me add that the *Oxford English Dictionary* indicates that the phrase *for example* is used as a "sentence adverbial" equivalent to *by way of illustration* or *as an example or instance*, and notes to compare it with the similar *for instance* and to the similar Middle French *pour exemple* and *par exemple*.

Am early instance in English is

> 1584   King James VI & I Ess. Prentise Poesie sig. Liijv,   **As for exempill**, ȝe man not say Then feir nocht Nor heir ocht.

Answer (score 3):

In *for example* and *for instance,* the word *for* indicates purpose. Here are some comparable uses of *for* in this sense:

> John Dillinger drove to the bank **for** the purpose of robbing it.
>
> Don't eat those fancy potato chips. I bought them **for** dinner, not **for** snackin'.
>
> The spoiler on sports cars is just **for** show. It doesn't serve any real aerodynamic purpose.
>
> **For** a good time, call 555-5555. *[To achieve the purpose of having a good time, call that phone number.]*
>
> I bought the ping-pong balls **for** the cat, not **for** you. *[I bought the ping-pong balls to benefit the cat, for the cat's sake, for the purpose of entertaining the cat—not to benefit you, etc.]*
>
> Kenneth Leahy built [this truck-tractor combo](https://www.farmshow.com/view_articles.php?a_id=543) just **for** fun.

*For example* is a fixed phrase: it has a customary meaning as a whole phrase, namely, to introduce an example. But this should not suggest that the individual words don't figure into the meaning of the phrase. Notice that the phrase is easily varied to suit variations in meaning:

> **For more examples** of money-laundering, see [Adam Khan's Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/Khanoisseur/status/817875178470445062).

Answer (score 2):

It is  idiomatic:

***[For example](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for+example)***
(idiom):

> ***As an illustrative instance:***
>
> - *Wear something simple; for example, a skirt and blouse.*

(AHD)

***[For example](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for-example):***

> ***You use for example to introduce and emphasize something which shows that something is true.***
>
> - ...'educational toys' that are designed to promote the development of, for example, children's spatial ability.
>   Take, for example, the simple sentence: 'The man climbed up the hill'.
>   A few simple precautions can be taken, for example ensuring that desks are the right height.

(Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

It's like:

> **The following sentence is *for* the purpose of giving an *example:*** blah blah blah

We simply shorten it to "for example."